# how to check if I have just accepted a discord server invite in java script

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a script that accepts discord invites and nitros before a human can, my only problem is checking for success to then send the webhook Here is the snippet:

```
async function autoInviteJoiner() {
        const {accounttoken} = await inquirer.prompt(accountTokenQuestion)
        console.log(accounttoken)
        console.log(
            chalk.green(`Provided account token: ${accounttoken}`)
        )
        const client = new Discord.Client();

        client.on('ready', () => {
            console.log(
                chalk.blue(`[${client.user.tag}] Monitoring for Server Invites ...`)
            )
        });
        
        client.on('message', message => {
            if (message.channel.id === CHANNEL_ID) {
                if(message.content.includes('discord.gg/')){
                    var v1 = performance.now();
                    
                    

                    console.log(
                        chalk.green(`[${client.user.tag}] Invite found in ${message.guild.name}`)
                    );
                    var removeFromString = message.content.split('remove ')[1];
                    var inviteCode = message.content.split('.gg/')[1];
                    var re = new RegExp(removeFromString,"g");

                    if (/\s/.test(inviteCode) || (/-/g.test(inviteCode) || (/_/g.test(inviteCode) || (re.test(inviteCode))))) {

                        function removeChar() {
                            if(message.content.includes('remove')){
                                //var removeFromString = message.content.split('remove ')[1];
                                //removeFromString()
                                //console.log(removeFromString)

                            }
                        
                        }
                        var value = inviteCode
                        var newcode = value.replace(/-/g, '').replace(/_/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(re, '');
                        //removeChar()
                        if (removeFromString == undefined) {
                            removeFromString = "nothing"
                        } 
                        console.log(
                            chalk.yellow(`Removed ${removeFromString} from the invite!`)
                        )
                        var slicedcode = newcode.slice(0, 6);
                        console.log(
                            chalk.blueBright(`Successfully extracted the final code: ${slicedcode} from the invite!`)
                        )

                        newInviteUrl = 'discord.gg/' + slicedcode
                        //var invite_url = message.content.split('.gg/')[1];
                        var invite_url = 'discord.gg/' + inviteCode

                        var requestResponse = request.post({
                            url: `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invites/${slicedcode}`,
                            headers: 
                            {
                            'Authorization': accounttoken
                            },
                        })
                    } else {
                        var invite_url = 'discord.gg/' + inviteCode
           
                        console.log(slicedcode)
    
        
                        var requestResponse = request.post({
                            url: `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invites/${inviteCode}`,
                            headers: 
                            {
                            'Authorization': accounttoken
                            },
                        })
                    }

                 var success = true;
                    if (success == true) {
                        console.log(
                            chalk.green(`[${client.user.tag}] Succesfully joined Invite`)
                        )
                        var v2 = performance.now();
                        var joinSpeed = (v2-v1)+" Ms"
                        

                        
                        const Hook = new webhook.Webhook("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/728328759199137804/FnwDCk5MfnZyseo1nTW9T_N35V6sPL-Euo3OzfOENqi-L_5wmLaT_QVWs7sAJlYlvz_U")
                        //console.log(Hook)

                        client.fetchInvite(invite_url)
                        .then(inv => {
                            //global.servername = inv.guild.name()
                            console.log('test')
                            console.log(invite_url)

                        
                            const msg = new webhook.MessageBuilder()
                            .setName("Void Scripts")
                            .setColor('#e3c010')
                            .setTitle('Void Scripts')
                            .setURL('https://twitter.com/SandalNsocks')
                            .setAuthor('Void Scripts', 'https://i.imgur.com/W0Q2dtX.png', 'https://twitter.com/SandalNsocks')
                            .addField('Successfully Joined Invite!', " ")
                            .setImage(`${inv.guild.iconURL}`)
                            .addField('Invite Code', `${inviteCode}`)
                            .addField('Server Name', `${inv.guild.name}`)
                            .addField('Join Speed', `${joinSpeed}`)
                            .setFooter('Void Scripts 0.0.1', 'https://i.imgur.com/W0Q2dtX.png')

                            Hook.send(msg)
                        })
                        

                        
                        
                        //chalk.green("total time  taken = "+(v2-v1)+"milliseconds")
                    } else {
                        console.log(
                            chalk.green('[ERROR] Failed to join invite')
                        )
                        var v2 = performance.now();
                        chalk.red("total time  taken = "+(v2-v1)+"milliseconds")

                        
                        
                        client.login(token);


                    }
                }
            }
            
        })
        client.login(accounttoken)
        .catch(error => {
            if(error.code == 4004) {
                console.log(`${chalk.red('[ERROR]')} - Invalid token`);

                
            } else {
                console.log(`${chalk.red('[ERROR]')} - ${error}`);
            }
        })

    }
```

In the current code i receive this error: `(node:14308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 400 Bad Request` When checking for success in order to send the webhook if anyone has a working method or a way to fix mine an answer would be greatly appreciated.